# Regex with letter in range abcd at least once

Tags: regex, lex

How would you write a regular expression that will return all words that contain each of a sequence of letters (such as abcd) at least once (may also contain other letters besides the required subsequence)?

abcd must be a subsequence of the word.

Thanks!

P.s. for use with lex

```
%{
%}

delim           [ \t\n]
ws              {delim}+
lc              [a-z]

%%
{ws}            {/* no action taken */}

(?={lc}*a)(?={lc}*b)(?={lc}*c)(?={lc}*d)            { /* some code */ }
%%
```

Comment: Example matching/non-matching input would be nice.

Comment: Must `abcd` be a substring, subsequence, or subset of the word?

Comment: Can you please edit that into the question? I've added an answer assuming the set of letters is static. If you don't know it before hand, you're probably better off writing code.

Comment: According to your example, you actually want `abcd` as a subset, not a subsequence. In `bnaanddc`, `abcd` is not a subsequence.

Comment: @larsmans - good point... thanks.  My mistake.  Its supposed to be a subsequence, not a subset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple pattern to check the existence of all letters in a word, using lookaheads:

```
\b(?=\w*a)(?=\w*b)(?=\w*c)(?=\w*d)\w+\b
```

You may want `^...$` instead of `\b...\b` if you want to *validate* the word, rather than *capture* it, and you may want to change `\w` to your acceptable alphabet.

Each `(?=\w*a)` token is a lookahead - it checks there are letters and an `a` ahead, but it doesn't advance - the next condition, `b`, is checked from the start again. The last `\w+` is what actually captures the word, after we've checked all letters are there.

Working example: http://rubular.com/r/L00DTpE813

See also: [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Width Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Wouldn't that state that a has to come before bcd?

Cheers!

Comment: @Nathanie - No, it doesn't! That would be `\w*a\w*b\w*c\w*d\w*`. I've added an explanation, and check the example link.

Comment: Got'cha!  Thanks!  Though not sure if lex supports that as it seems to generate  an unrecognized rule error ...

Comment: @Nathaniel - Can you post how you're using it? Must it be done with a single regex? It's a trivial task if you can run a line of code...

Answer (score 0):

```
\b\w*abcd\w*\b
```

This regex matches all words containing `abcd` character sequence..

Comment: Sorry, should have stated, it needs to be a subsequence of the word.

Answer (score 0):

If `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` have to appear in this order, the following pattern
will match:

```
{lc}*a{lc}*b{lc}*c{lc}*d{lc}*   { /* some code */ }
```

If there isn't such order constraint, as *Kobi* answered, look-ahead will be
needed.
Though flex has 
[trailing context](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html), there are [limitations](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Limitations.html),
and won't meet complex look-ahead purpose.